# AkkaHttp - Making a Client inside a Server

Tags: scala, akka-http

I built an Akka-Http Client inside a Server, which gets a GET request by a browser and then uses it's one parameter to make a POST request to Twitter. Then, the server makes a JSON string out of the Twitter's response and gives it back to the browser.

[image: This image describes this simple interaction]

So, my code works. It does. The problem is it works only once. If I call GET /StepOne for a second time, it fails.

```
val route = cors(settings){
  path("StepOne"){
    get {
      parameters('callback.as[String])(cb => {
        val callback = this.encodeUriComp(cb)
        val url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
        var response: String = null
        this.oauth_timestamp = this.createTimestamp()
        this.oauth_nonce = this.randomString(32)
        val authorization = headers.RawHeader("Authorization",
          """OAuth oauth_callback="""" + callback +
            """", oauth_consumer_key="""" + this.consumerKey +
            """", oauth_nonce="""" + this.oauth_nonce +
            """", oauth_signature="""" + this.encodeUriComp(this.createSignature()) +
            """", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="""" + this.oauth_timestamp +
            """", oauth_version="1.0"""")
        val params = ByteString(callback)
        var jsonRSP = "null string"
        val responseFuture: Future[HttpResponse] = Http().singleRequest(HttpRequest(HttpMethods.POST, url,
          headers = List(authorization),
          entity = HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`text/plain(UTF-8)`, params)))
        responseFuture
          .onComplete {
            case Success(res) => {
              val response = res._3.dataBytes.map(_.utf8String).runForeach(body => {
                /* We postedit the string to make it JSON Parsable */
                 jsonRSP = "{" + body.replaceAll("=", ":")
                                     .replaceAll("&", ",")
                                     .replaceAll("([\\w-]+)", "\"$1\"") + "}"
               // jsonRSP = postBody
                println(jsonRSP)

              })
            }
            case Failure(_) => sys.error("Couldn't get into api.twitter")
          } 
        implicit val timeout = Timeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        Await.result(responseFuture, timeout.duration)
        println(jsonRSP)
        complete(HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`application/json`, jsonRSP))
      })
    }
  }
}
```

So as you can see, I declare a var called JsonRSP which initially prints "null string". After that I make the POST call and I edit the JsonRSP with the information given by Twitter. The second time I call this StepOne API, the JsonRSP string isn't edited and it prints the "null string" over again. This happens despite the fact that Twitter gives me the right information every time.

So, for example, the first time I get:

```
{"oauth_token":"mytoken","oauth_token_secret":"mysecrettoken","oauth_callback_confirmed":"true"}
```

But the second time I call my API it returns:

"Null String"

Any ideas? I'm well known for making obvious mistakes so please help me !

________ EDIT ______

I've edited the code to get rid of an aux variable that wasn't needed at all.
So the main thing here is that if I print jsonRSP inside de runForeach it prints the correct JSON. But when I print it before doing the complete it prints "null string" all over again. To make it weirder, it still completes the right json the first time, but "null string" the second time. So I don't have a clue why is this happening. If my code shoudln't work, it shouldn't work everytime, so why does it work the first time?

Comment: When you call the route stepOne 2nd time what is the error message can you just add the error message here?

Comment: Where do you print `jsonRSP` ? Because I see only `println(postBody)`.

Comment: @RamanMishra, there's no Error Message. That's the problem I've got. I've edited the code. Now I don't use the aux var "postBody". Instead, I change the value directly into JsonRSP (postBody wasn't needed at all so I got rid of it). So, to make myself clearer: There's no error message. If I print JsonRSP in my console it works both times, but the complete() that I get in the browser only sends the Json once, the second time it sends "null string". Hope this clears it out.

Comment: @tea-addict Hi man, I just edited the code. Now I don't use the aux var "postBody". Instead, I change the value directly into JsonRSP (postBody wasn't needed at all so I got rid of it). It's cleaner now, but it doesn't change my problem at all.

Comment: @Francisco Arriagada Arroyo , Can you print `val response`, because I think you don't assign it properly. Can you remove whole `jsonRSP`, you don't need it.

Comment: @tea-addict Doing what you told me, my response val prints: "scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@3ef7868e"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I chose what is cleaner. Thanks to @tea-adict 's response I came up with this code.

```
val settings = CorsSettings.defaultSettings.withAllowCredentials(false)
val route = cors(settings){
  path("StepOne"){
    get {
      parameters('callback.as[String])(cb => {
        val callback = this.encodeUriComp(cb)
        val url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
        this.oauth_timestamp = this.createTimestamp()
        this.oauth_nonce = this.randomString(32)
        val authorization = headers.RawHeader("Authorization",
          """OAuth oauth_callback="""" + callback +
            """", oauth_consumer_key="""" + this.consumerKey +
            """", oauth_nonce="""" + this.oauth_nonce +
            """", oauth_signature="""" + this.encodeUriComp(this.createSignature()) +
            """", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="""" + this.oauth_timestamp +
            """", oauth_version="1.0"""")
        val params = ByteString(callback)


        val responseFuture: Future[HttpResponse] = Http().singleRequest(HttpRequest(HttpMethods.POST, url,
          headers = List(authorization),
          entity = HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`text/plain(UTF-8)`, params)))


        implicit val timeout = Timeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        try {
          val result = Await.result(responseFuture, timeout.duration)
          complete(HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`text/plain(UTF-8)`,result.entity.dataBytes))
        }
        catch{
          case e: TimeoutException => complete(HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`text/plain(UTF-8)`,"oauth_token=null&oauth_token_secret=null&callback_confirmed=false"))
        }

      })
    }
  }
}
```

It doesn't complete a JSON string. Instead, it sends the same plain-text gotten from Twitter back to the front-end app. Then, I will simply take that response in my front-end and transform it to a JSON string to parse it and work with it.

It's much cleaner this way.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is related with `Future`, because you don't wait for response actually, `complete(HttpEntity(ContentTypes.'application/json', jsonRSP))`, you always return `jsonRSP`. You should wait for `Future` computation and then return it.

```
val route = cors(settings){
    path("StepOne"){
        get {
        parameters('callback.as[String])(cb => {
            val callback = this.encodeUriComp(cb)
            val url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
            var response: String = null
            this.oauth_timestamp = this.createTimestamp()
            this.oauth_nonce = this.randomString(32)
            val authorization = headers.RawHeader("Authorization",
            """OAuth oauth_callback="""" + callback +
                """", oauth_consumer_key="""" + this.consumerKey +
                """", oauth_nonce="""" + this.oauth_nonce +
                """", oauth_signature="""" + this.encodeUriComp(this.createSignature()) +
                """", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="""" + this.oauth_timestamp +
                """", oauth_version="1.0"""")
            val params = ByteString(callback)
            val responseFuture: Future[HttpResponse] = Http().singleRequest(HttpRequest(HttpMethods.POST, url,
            headers = List(authorization),
            entity = HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`text/plain(UTF-8)`, params)))
            responseFuture
            .onComplete {
                case Success(res) => {
                res._3.dataBytes.map(_.utf8String).runForeach(body => {
                    /* We postedit the string to make it JSON Parsable */
                    "{" + body.replaceAll("=", ":")
                                        .replaceAll("&", ",")
                                        .replaceAll("([\\w-]+)", "\"$1\"") + "}"
                })
                }
                case Failure(_) => sys.error("Couldn't get into api.twitter")
            } 
            implicit val timeout = Timeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            val result = Await.result(responseFuture, timeout.duration)
            complete(HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`application/json`, result))
        })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. However, 'result' is not a JSON parseable string that I could return in complete. So that code won't work as such. I'm trying to solve that now, so if I can, I will accept this answer as the correct one. Thank you!

Comment: I think `case Success` and `case Failure` should both return JSON. I am not sure what is `sys.error`?

Comment: @FranciscoArriagadaArroyo don't forget to accept the answer!

Comment: @tea-addict The main problem is that I can't get the json outside RunForeach. If I could do it, returning it in the complete would be straightforward :(